# NSBox is not showing methods to add content in it (Swift)

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, xcode6

I would need to add some contents inside a NSBox, an Image and some text.
To do that I use the methods of NSBox class and call them on the object.

I created an IBOutlet:

`@IBOutlet weak var theBox: NSBox!`

and I also have a button, once I click it, the box will be filled with text (NSTextField):

```
@IBAction func filler(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var label: NSTextField! = NSTextField()   //Initialized a label to put it in the box
    label.stringValue = "My text hey hey hey!"

    theBox.setContentView(label)       //I GET AN ERROR MESSAGE HERE
}
```

to add the content I used `.setContentView`but this method is not callable on the object `theBox`and I don't know why I am wrong. Look at the documentation. The method exists and it is callable on the NSBox objects.

I'm new with swift and OSX development. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, you don't call the `set` methods for properties, you just assign to them directly:

```
theBox.contentView = label
```